# Angular 5 - JSON with selection

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a Question. I have a json File this looks like so.

```
[{
"nagelplatten": [
    {
        "kg" : "1000",
        "rabatt" : "3",
        "fracht" : ""  
    }
],
"metalwebs": [
    {
        "kg" : "1",
        "rabatt" : "4",
        "fracht" : ""
    }
]
}]
```

And my function looks so. So we can i become only "metalwebs"?

```
this.ns.getRabatt().subscribe(res => this.rabatte = res);
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.ns.getRabatt().subscribe((res : any) => this.rabatte = res[0].metalwebs);
```

Comment: Oh that was easy. Thx for you Help

Comment: This will work only if Json is having only one object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of multiple objects as above and you want to make an array of objects containing ony `metalwebs`

```
this.ns.getRabatt().subscribe(res => 
    this.rabatte = Array.from(res,r=>{return {metalwebs:r.metalwebs}});
);
```

this will make your JSON as follow

```
[{
  "metalwebs": [
      {
        "kg" : "1",
        "rabatt" : "4",
        "fracht" : ""
     }
  ]
},
{
  "metalwebs": [
      {
        "kg" : "2",
        "rabatt" : "8",
        "fracht" : ""
     }
  ]
}]
```